# loop through columns and generate rows for each record R

Tags: r, loops, sas, hierarchical-data

When I used to program in SAS, it was easy to loop across variables and generate rows after applying some sort of logic. I would like to do this in R. To illustrate, consider the following scenario.

```
Input
+----+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
| ID |      lvl1      |        lvl2       |     lvl3    |
+----+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 |  United States |  Ohio             |  Cincinnati |
|  2 |  Ohio          |  Cincinnati       |             |
|  3 |  Canada        |  British Columbia |  Vancouver  |
+----+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Let array _lvl contain lvl1, lvl2, and lvl3 and loop from i = 1 to 3 (the upper bound).

1. Loop 1: _lvl(1) Check whether lvl1 is null and output if not, supplying null values for the other values.
2. Loop 2: _lvl(2) Check whether lvl1 is null or lvl2 is null and output if not, supplying null for lvl3.
3. Loop 3: _lvl(3) Check whether lvl1 is null, lvl2 is null, or lvl3 is null and output if not.

This should produce the following for ID = 2.

```
Output
+----+-------+-------------+-------+
| ID |  lvl1 |     lvl2    |  lvl3 |
+----+-------+-------------+-------+
|  2 |  Ohio |             |       |
|  2 |  Ohio |  Cincinnati |       |
+----+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's not clear to me what the exact nature of what you are doing is. Are you saying that you are checking each column's rows in turn to see if that row's column or its precedents in the row are null?

Comment: Intention is to expand the hierarchy and generate a separate record for each level of a lineage. (Grandfather, Father, Son would result in 3 records: Grandfather; Grandfather, Father; Grandfather, Father, Son.)

Comment: Please use `dput` for providing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too keen on your particular use case, but I'm sympathetic to the general struggle of adjusting to R after using the SAS data step in this way.

The way I emulate output statements in data step in R, is by applying functions along the rows (or in this case, columns) of a data frame.

Define your "array" of column names:

```
lvl <- c('lvl1','lvl2','lvl3')
```

Then mimic the SAS output statements using a function (with `i` playing the same role as the index of your SAS array, `data` representing the input data frame, and `names` being the entire vector of columns names to iterate over):

```
outputcriteria <- function(i, data, names) {
  data <- data[!is.na(data[,names[i]]),] #exclude rows with NA in the current column
  data[,names[-(1:i)]] <- NA             #blank out columns after the current column
  return (data)
}
```

Then apply this function to your data frame `df` with `lapply()` by setting the input vector to `1:length(lvl)` (the index of your vector of column names), and also passing the `data` and `name` arguments into the function:

```
l <- lapply(1:length(lvl), outputcriteria, data = df, names = lvl)
```

The result `l` is a list of three data frames (one for each iteration), which you can `rbind` into a single data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, l)
```

The main difference is that you end up reading the data three times and outputting a data frame each time, as opposed to reading it once in SAS.

Comment: Interesting approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt using some indexing to blank out values where appropriate:

```
newdat <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat),each=3),]
newdat[-1][upper.tri(dat[-1])[rep(1:nrow(dat),3),]] <- ""
unique(newdat)

#    ID          lvl1             lvl2       lvl3
#1    1 United States                            
#1.1  1 United States             Ohio           
#1.2  1 United States             Ohio Cincinnati
#2    2          Ohio                            
#2.1  2          Ohio       Cincinnati           
#3    3        Canada                            
#3.1  3        Canada British Columbia           
#3.2  3        Canada British Columbia  Vancouver
```

This works because the created matrix is an indicator of which parts to delete of `newdat`:

```
upper.tri(dat[-1])[rep(1:nrow(dat),3),]
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="ID,lvl1,lvl2,lvl3    
1,United States,Ohio,Cincinnati
2,Ohio,Cincinnati,
3,Canada,British Columbia,Vancouver", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```